# AWS Network Load balancer with nginx ingress issue in setting target group attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I move my classic load balancer with nginx ingress to a Network Load balancer with nginx ingress.
I use this manifets file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml

But my application requires:

- attribute: Proxy protocol v2
- healthcheck protocol: TCP
- healthcheck port: traffic-port

I modified the following block with:

```
    # Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: SSL_CERT_ARN
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: proxy_protocol_v2.enabled="true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-protocol: "TCP"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port: "traffic-port"
```

But none of the folllowing is taken into account:

```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: proxy_protocol_v2.enabled="true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-protocol: "TCP"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port: "traffic-port"
```

My EKS cluster is 1.19.
The previous settings are available in AWS Load Blancer 2.2 at least (https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/#nlb-target-type)

I guess my manifest is not taking the right version for the AWS LB, so unable to apply, but I don't know where to set this.

Should I adapt the livenessProbe and readinessProbe sections ?

Do you know how to have these settings working in the manifest ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't manage to toggle this automatically via the annotations, so I did it manually via Load Balancer -> Listeners -> Target group (multiple) -> Attributes -> Proxy Protocol